# Symbol std could not be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

So here is what happened.

I installed eclipse and eclipse-cdt through apt-get command: `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-cdt`. I launched Eclipse and created a default C++ project (Image 1) and then I have this unresolved symbols `std`, `cout`, `endl`.

I use 64-bit Linux Mint 16, so `gcc` is installed by default and I don't have to bother to install any additional C++ software.

So the question is why on Earth it has these unresolved references and how can I resolved them?

Other links recommend to `include <stdio.h>` ([link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814536/eclipse-c-symbol-std-could-not-be-resolved)), or to search for unresolved references ([link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803685/eclipse-cdt-symbol-cout-could-not-be-resolved)) -- but neither of them helped/worked.

I assume the problem is that it doesn't see some specific paths to the libraries, but then how can I find those paths and include them by default?

**EDIT 1:**

If I run `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp` in a command-line I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Are you able to compile on the command-line?

Comment: You'll probably need to install the build-essential package. `gcc` is not C++.

Comment: If I  just do `gcc -std=c++11 test.cpp` in command line , I get this: `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: @FredLarson I have the newest version

Comment: Use `g++`, not `gcc`. `gcc` doesn't link the C++ libraries by default.

Comment: @FredLarson the mistakes are the same as before... even if there were not, how can I resolve this without using bash, but using eclipse?

Comment: I'm not certain you're using the right toolchain. Are you cross compiling for another platform?

Comment: @FredLarson No, I'm not. I can change it to Linux GCC, but in addition to those unresolved references that I have now, I also have unresolved inclusion for include statements.

Comment: I still think you need the build-essential package. I don't know about Mint, but Ubuntu doesn't come with C++ by default.

Comment: Can you successfully run `echo '#include<iostream>' | g++ -x c++ -o /dev/null -c -`?

Comment: FredLarson I have build-essential. @Rufflewind Yes, I can run this without mistakes. It does nothing.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov When you get `undefined reference to main` that means your source code does not have a main function and you are compiling without the `-c` flag.  That is normal behavior.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov When you get missing headers, however, that is not normal.  What command did you use to run the compilation?

Comment: Check out this question, also about compiling on Mint: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19500018/10077

Comment: @Rufflewind In eclipse I didn't run the test.cpp: it just highlights these undefined references. In bash I ran `gcc -std=c++11 test.cpp` (or without -std parameter).

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Don't use `gcc`.  Use `g++`.

Comment: @Rufflewind I tried with g++ -- it's the same.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Paste the full error message in your question.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Can you try to run this and see if it produces any error? `echo -e '#include<iostream>\nint main(){}' | g++ -x c++ -o /dev/null -`

Comment: @FredLarson If I locate `stdio.h` then I get this: `/home/sergey/bin/boost_1_57_0/boost/iostreams/filter/stdio.hpp
/usr/include/stdio.h
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tr1/stdio.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h
/usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/CORE/nostdio.h
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/help/matlab/ref/h5p.set_fapl_stdio.html
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/lcc/include/stdio.h
/usr/local/include/boost/iostreams/filter/stdio.hpp
`

Comment: @Rufflewind No, it doesn't produce anything.

Comment: @SergeyIvanov Are you absolutely sure your `test.cpp` contains a `main` function then?  Run `grep main test.cpp` just to be sure.

Comment: @Rufflewind You're right. Looks like I was running command on unsaved version of the file. Your command still doesn't produce any error, though. However, now Eclipse doesn't highlight those unresolved references. How can I run this code within Eclipse?

Comment: @SergeyIvanov I don't really know Eclipse, but ... press the Build button?