# Symbol std could not be resovled Eclipse Mars C/C++

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I installed Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 14.04. When I try create an empty project and simple program I get the error `"Symbol std could not be resovled"` , and the same for`cout`. But when I run the Hello world project included in Eclipse, everything works fine. What might be the problem?

```
Current toolchain : Linux GCC
Current builder : GNU make builder
GCC Archiver
GCC C++ Compiler
GCC C Compiler
GCC C Linker
GCC C++ Linker
GCC Assembler
```

Example code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
    cout << "Hello"; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code of that simple program which is giving this error?

Comment: `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 
 cout << "Hello";
 return 0;
}`

Comment: Tried these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814536/eclipse-c-symbol-std-could-not-be-resolved